# Username and Password validation always returns true (with firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2

I'm currently working on validation or uniqueness of username in my Vue.js project with firebase.

My approach goes like this. First I'll store all the registered/saved users in an array under the `created` hook using the vue-resource:

```js
//RETRIEVE REGISTERED TAILORS
    this.$http.get('https://nots-76611.firebaseio.com/tailors.json').then(function(data){
      return data.json();
    }).then(function(data){
      var usersArray = [];
      for (let key in data){
          data[key].id = key;
          usersArray.push(data[key]);
      }
      this.regTailors = usersArray;
    });
```

the array will contain two users with the username *dyalibidyalibi* and *marantzmarantz*, and password *dyalibidyalibi* and *marantzmarantz* consecutively (usernames and passwords are the same).

then after that, under the `computed` properties, I loop through the array and check if NEITHER of the currently entered password or username matches one of the users in the array. If that's the case then it's unique and will return `true` else, it is not unique and will return `false`:

```js
isUnique: function(){
      for (var i = 0; i < this.regTailors.length; i++) {
        if((this.tailor.tUsername!=this.regTailors[i].tUsername) && (this.tailor.tPassword!=this.regTailors[i].tPassword))
         return true;
        else
         return false;
      }
    }
```

when I try to enter *sonny* and *sonny* for both username and password, the console shows `true` which is the expected output. then I tried *marantzmarantz* and *sonny* (and vice versa) it shows `false`, which is expected again. BUT when I tried entering *dyalibidyalibi* and *sonny* (and vice versa), it shows `true` which should not be the case since one of the registered users has already the username or password of *dyalibidyalibi*!

is there something wrong with my looping? or my boolean expression? how do I fix this so that users who will register will always have the unique username and password before saving it to the database?

**EDIT: I put some `console.log()` inside the `for` loop and it seems that the counter `i` is stuck at 0 and it never reaches 1. I checked the length of the array and it always displays 2 so I think there's no problem on the length. What seems to be the problem that I'm missing? it's been two days and I can't figure it out**

Comment: It looks to me like you're returning true when anything *doesn't* match.  Isn't that the opposite of what you're looking for?

Comment: @theGleep yes, it is what I'm aiming for. being `true` means the username and password is being unique

Comment: So you're wanting to make sure that ... ? no username matches any passwords ?  Or that no two usernames match?  Or that the username is not already in the database?

Comment: @theGleep username and password can match. yes, no two usernames and password match. yes, both the username and the password must not exist in the database. but username and password can be identical.

Comment: Are these passwords being encrypted into the database? I also don't see why password matching is important. Alternatively, Firebase has its own authentication tools if you would like to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent my `for` loop code snippet to my friend and he stated to me the concept of *short circuiting* in a loop where the loop stops because of the `return` (credits for @Ricardo Orellana for pointing that out too) so I figured that instead of returning a boolean, I'll just assign it to a declared variable and `return` it afterwards. I'll loop through the array finding a match of username and password. If it matches, I'll assign `false` to a variable and `break` the loop. If not, assign `true` and loop untill the end.

```js
isUnique: function(){
      let result;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.regTailors.length; i++) {
        if((this.tailor.tUsername!=this.regTailors[i].tUsername) && (this.tailor.tPassword!=this.regTailors[i].tPassword))
         result = true;
        else{
         result = false;
         break;
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you try a solution using the built-in function `find`, in this case you want to compare one value against an array using a `for` loop and returning a boolean value as soon as the evaluation is satisfied, however this evaluation is going to stop as soon as your conditions gets satisfied, why? because a `for` loop clause gets stopped with the `return` key, it is similar to when you return a value in function (it stops function execution).

So try something like this:

```
isUnique() {
  var hasTheSameValue = ['dyalibidyalibi', 'marantzmarantz'].find(function (elemOfArrayToEvaluate) {
    return elemOfArrayToEvaluate === 'Your current username or pass value';
  })

  if (hasTheSameValue) {
    // has the same value so it's not unique
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }

}
```

You may find further information about `find` function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: I'm having difficulty in understanding the concept of `find()` so I'm sorry I can't dwell on self -studying this for too long because my thesis defense will be two days from now and I have many modules to implement. I'll try to study it in the future. BUT thank you for pointing out the idea of the loop breaking because of the `return`. It helped me a lot in solving my own problem.

Comment: I am glad to help you, and your solution using a loop is valid too.